# Do I have the right idea of piecewise continuity functions?

Tags: continuity, piecewise-continuity

I'm currently studying continuity of functions and I like to use [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/continuity%20y%3D%20%5Cbegin%7Bcases%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%7D%7Bx-1%7D%26x%5Cle%201%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%2B2%26x%3E%201%5Cend%7Bcases%7D%2C%20x%3D1?or=input) to study.

The teacher told us that a function is continuous at $x=a$ if

1. $a$ is defined in the piecewise function(if has one)
2. $f(a)$ is defined
3. $\lim _{x\to a}\:\:f\left(x\right)$ = f(a)

The teacher never explained how piecewise functions work. He just assumed we knew. And as soon as I saw one I intuitively knew(or thought I knew) seemed pretty straight forward, the left side is the function to use whenever the right side condition is met for x.

So I gave symbolab a piecewise function, precisely [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/continuity%20y%3D%20%5Cbegin%7Bcases%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2B2%7D%7Bx-1%7D%26x%5Cle%201%5C%5C%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%2B2%26x%3E%201%5Cend%7Bcases%7D%2C%20x%3D1?or=input) function:

$continuity\:y=\:\begin{cases}\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}&x\le \:1\\ x+2&x>\:1\end{cases},\:x=1$

Symbolab concluded that $f(x)$ is continous at $x=1$

Before this, I thought this function wasn't continuous at $x=1$ because if $x=1$ I thought it would use the function next to the condition $x ≤ 1$. That is:

$f\left(1\right)=\frac{1^2+2}{1-1}=undefined$

but instead, symbolab used the second part of the piecewise function to evaluate $f(1)$

$f\left(1\right)=1+2$

Either

1. I don't know how piecewise functions work.
2. I'm missing something about continuous functions
3. Symbolab has a bug

Since the first 2 are the most probable, I ask here. What am I missing?

For those who are programmers this my thought process:

$g(x)=\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}$

$f(x)=x-1$

$\:eval(x)=\:\begin{cases}g\left(x\right)&x\le \:1\\ f\left(x\right)&x>\:1\end{cases},\:x=1$

```
function eval(x){
  if(x<=1)
     return g(x);
  else 
     return f(x);
}
```

Thus

```
print(eval(1)); //undefined || div0 || crash
```

Comment: There is a typo in the definitionof the function. It does not even make sense .

Comment: The question should have $x<1$ as $1$ is not in the domain .

Comment: @RamanujanXV so you are saying that the right side should be in the domain of the left side function? I thought the right side was a condition for x to met only.

Comment: What I mean to say is that you cannot have $x\leq1$. Instead it should be $x<1$ due to reasons mentioned beforehand.

Comment: I'll ask again refrasing it. Sorry, my english is not my first language. If I cannot have x ≤ 1 that means that the condition has to include only numbers within the domain of the function on the left. Am I right?

Comment: I'll guide you thru my thought process. I thought this condition was just a condition x have to meet only. So if i give f(1) since 1 ≤ 1 it would use the function on the left of that condition, no matter if the function on the left is not defined for that value I was expecting f(1) = undefinied

Comment: @centenond I have edited the answer to correct a mistake .Do check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error while defining the function.

$y=\:\begin{cases}\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}&x\le \:1\\ x+2&x>\:1\end{cases}$

Here,writing $x\leq1$ makes the question erroneous as $1$ is not in the domain of the function.

Therefore, the correct way of defining the function should be :

$y=\:\begin{cases}\frac{x^2+2}{x-1}&x<1\\ x+2&x>\:1\end{cases}$

Edit: As @ryang rightly pointed out that the function is continuous because at $x=1$, the function is not defined and that's the point where the limit doesn't exist, but continuity of a function is discussed within its domain.

Comment: The bottom function is continuous.

Comment: @ryang But the limit doesn't exist..

Comment: It’s a [matter of contention](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10600/372), I guess.

Comment: @ryang Ah yes,I remember my professor telling us about this..He specifically gave us the example of $\tan x$.

Comment: @ryang Thank you for pointing it out